# подключение к почтовому серверу

Tags: сеть, email, ip, домен

Есть свой почтовый сервер поднятый на NAS Synology и есть приложение на next.js которое живет на виртуалной машине на том же NAS, тоесть сервер приложения и почтовый сервер находяться в одной локальной сети.

Необходимо расслыть письма из приложения по средствам почтового сервера.

Проблема заключаеться в следующем - при попытке отправить письмо приложение не может подключиться к серверу по средствам доменного имени пишет - `connect ECONNREFUSED (внешний статичный ip):587` при этом сопоставление доменого имени с ip происходит верно.
При этом если приложение запустить вне локальной сети, всё отлично работает и приложение отлично подключеться к почтовому серверу и письма отправляються.

Если в качестве хоста сервера вместо доменного имени указать внутрений ip 192.168.1.100 то подключение вроде как проходит но начинает ругаться на сертификат
`Error [ERR_TLS_CERT_ALTNAME_INVALID]: Hostname/IP does not match certificate's altnames: IP: 192.168.1.100 is not in the cert's list: \n`
Самоподписной сертификат пробовал подкидывать не помогает начинает ругаться- мол нормальный давай.

Comment: Какому конкретно устройству принадлежит «внешний статичный ip»? Небось роутеру какому-нибудь?

Comment: да, порты на NAS проброшены

Comment: Значит это может намекать на то, что роутер по какой-то причине не хочет пробрасывать порты для подключений из локальной сети, и видимо нужно ковырять его настройки

Comment: Хотя если виртуалка находится на NAS, то может оказаться рациональнее тупо прописать локальный ip для домена на локальном DNS или в файле /etc/hosts или типа того, зачем локальный трафик через роутер гонять

Answer (score 0):

помогла простая запись в файле /etc/hosts